# What is the Pythonic way to find the type of an instance from the base class?

Tags: python, inheritance

Consider the following (silly) MWE:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class CarABC(ABC):
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.color, self.name)

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def clone(self, color):
        car = type(self)
        return car(color)

class Ford(CarABC):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__("Ford", color)


    def run(self):
        print("Ford is running")


class Toyota(CarABC):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__("Toyota", color)

    def run(self):
        print("Toyota is running")
```

where the purpose of `clone` method is to create a new car of the same type but different color.

Obviously since the `clone` operation is common among all classes inheriting from `CarABC` it should be a method of the base class.  However, the method needs to know the child class that has invoked it to return a car of the correct type.

I was wondering if the way I used in the example is correct (and Pythonic) for figuring out the type of the base class that has invoked the method?

Comment: `isinstance` should answer you the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance

Comment: I am not sure.  `isinstance` only checks, for example, if `self` is a `Ford` or a `Toyota`.  It does not return the type.

Comment: But isn't that exactly what you achieve by printing "yx is running"? Ahh: sorry...no i get it...bu no idea ;)

Comment: My question was about what I am doing in the `clone` method, not `run` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Functions - class **type**(*object*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) (**emphasis** is mine):

> With one argument, return the type of an object. The return value is a type object and generally the same object as returned by [object.__class__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__).
>
> The **[isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) built-in function is recommended** for testing the type of an object, because it takes subclasses into account.

Using *isinstance* here would obviously be a bad design decision, as the base class would have to know (and iterate over) all its child classes.

A cleaner *clone* method variant would be:

```py
def clone(self, color):
    cls = self.__class__
    return cls(color)
```

The drawback would be that if you add some other (non default) arguments to a child class initializer, you won't be able to instantiate it.

As a note, using *type* in this case would be *OK* (and it would probably be the only way if using *old style classes* - but those exist in *Python 2.* only).